# Changing the name of the Ubuntu partition?

Tags: filesystem, gparted, live-environment

I know the procedure for changing the label of a volume: open GParted, click the disk, right click the partition, select Label File System. But when I try to apply the procedure to the partition that contains Ubuntu, Label File System is disabled.

Is this just because Ubuntu is running from that partition, or is there a more sinister reason? That is, if I boot a live Ubuntu and label the partition from there, will it work just fine, or will it damage my Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Yes it's currently 'active' because it's mounted, and your system protects it in this state and thus won't let you change even the partition's label.  Booting a 'live' media (such as Ubuntu install ISO) would allow you to change label, and won't impact your installation.

Comment: While I try to use gparted to make both labels filesystem & partition (GUID) has two, I sometimes use disks. I think gparted want partition unmounted. See if Disks works. Also command line `sudo tune2fs -L <label> <dev>`